# Given area enclosed under a unknown parabola and finding x intercepts

Tags: definite-integrals, area

> The area enclosed by the curve $f(x)=24+ax-x^{2}$ , the co-ordinate axes, and the ordinate $x=$6, is $108$. If $m$ and $n$ are the $x$-axis intercepts of the graph of $y=f(x)$, find the value of $$m+n+a.$$

Attempts: 
Im kind of confused over the graphs , $m$ can be $<or>$ $6$ but when we take $m<6$ I'm getting a cubic equation as $2m^{3}-3am^{2}+54a-144m-540=0$ now if my method is correct how do i solve this , if i get the value of $a$ then then i could substitute $y=0$ and get the value of $n$ 
Or any other shorter approaches ?

Comment: Since the roots of $f$ are $m, n$, glancing at the leading coefficient of the polynomial defining $f$ gives that $f(x) = -(x - m) (x - n)$. Expanding and comparing coefficients gives...

Comment: @Travis but then any use of $x=6$ ?

Comment: Well, my hint only gives that $m + n = a$, so to determine the sum we still need to determine $a$.

Comment: @Travis where exactly am i to use that relation $m+n=a$ , i tried a lot to manipulate it into my equation .

Comment: Since we know that $m + n = a$, we know that $m + n + a = 2 a$, so it's now enough just to determine $a$. What is your integral expression for the area?

Comment: @Travis i integrated the equation from 0 to m and added modulus of area from m to 6 equated it with 108 and got final equation as $2m^{3}-3am^{2}+54a-144m-540=0$

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. In that case, we should, I think, be able to eliminate a variable using the identity $mn = -24$ (again from the equation in my first hint). This will give up to four possible solutions for $m$, but only those in $[0, 6]$ have any meaning for this case.

Comment: In fact, by a monotonicity argument I think we should expect there is exactly one solution with $m$ in that range.

Comment: @Travis yes I'm also reaching at an irreducible quadratic expression so any other alternate methods btw **final answer is 4**

Comment: I don't see where $4$ comes from; I get a solution of $m = 2.762...$, which corresponds to $a = -5.926\ldots$. Perhaps *area* here should really refer to *signed area*?

Comment: @Travis try doing it reverse the answer seems legit only

Comment: @Travis we just need to prove that $m(positive$ $root)=6$ or something

Comment: It's true that $m = 6$ gives a solution: In this case, we get $n = -4$ and $a = 2$. But there is also a second solution with $0 < m < 6$, namely the one I mention above.

Comment: @Travis but only one value of 'm' is possible . Can you please tell me how you got that other answer too ?

Comment: No, using your formulation of the problem (i.e., counting area under the $x$-axis as positive), there are two solutions. To find these solutions, I solved for $a$ in terms of $m$ using the two relations in the first hint, and substituted in the above equation, $2 m^3 - 3 a m^2 + \cdots = 0$. This gives a quartic equation, and it has two roots in the interval $[0, 6]$ of interest.

Comment: @Travis hmm , btw whats the value of $a$ you got , we could substitute at $x=6$, and if $f(x)$ turns out to be $=0$ then we will be able to conclude everything .

Comment: I gave it above, it's $-5.926\ldots$, but I don't know what you mean by "substitute at $x = 6$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rereading the question carefully

> ......$f(x)=24+ax-x^{2}$ , **the co-ordinate axes, and the ordinate
>   $x=$6, is $108$.** If ....

So the case of $m>6$ is clearly ruled out as the area in that case between both coordinate **axes** and $f(x)$ and ordinate $x=6$ will become $\infty$ . ( Think ..... draw it out and check .... still don't get it .... leave a comment)

So now integrating directly as

$\int_{0}^{6} 24+ax-x^{2} =108$

And solving for $a$ we have $a=2$

Now Since the roots of $f$ are $m, n$,

$f(x) = -(x - m) (x - n)$. Expanding and comparing coefficients gives $m+n=a$

Therefore we have $m+n+a=4$